# Wordpress Autocorrect URL / Slugs Does Not Work

Tags: url-rewriting

As you know wordpress tries to auto-complete a URL when it is not exits and / or written wrong.

When a user enters URLs like /in-correct-url wordpress redirect that user to /correct-url I mean, redirects incoming links to the proper URL

But this feature does not work for my site. I tried to deactived all the plugins and switched theme also updated the wordpress version but nothing changed. What might be the problem ?

Comment: What are the actual slugs you are trying this with? WordPress just does a `LIKE` query on whatever the incorrect slug is, so if the wrong slug is not an exact match for part of the real slug, it won't work.

Comment: Yes i know. I'am just deleting one letter at the end of a random post URL but it redirects me to 404 page. Normally it should redirect me to post URL

Comment: Here is the example from my site [link](http://wpmavi.com/wordpress-eklentileri-plugins/wordpress-301-yonlendirme-redirection.html) you can go the URL that i share and delete one letter or one word at the end. You will see it will redirect you to 404 page not the actual post

Comment: That's because you put `.html` as a static element in your permalink structure, those characters are not part of the slug. If you delete anything before that it will correctly redirect.

Comment: Yes. You are right i did not notice that. Thank you for your help!